# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0){
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quwey)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];
    $link = $row['link'];

    echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>$description<br /> <br />";            
  }     
} else {
  echo "No results found for \"<b>$keywords</b>\""; 
}
```

I can find out whats wrong with it.

Comment: Have you tried to read the error message?

Comment: please check variable name `$query` not `$quwey`

Comment: you can simply test print you query and run directly in mysql

Comment: is it a typo `mysql_fetch_assoc($quwey)` `$quwey` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   mysql_fetch_assoc($quwey)
```

you typed "$quwey" instead of "$query"

Answer (score 0):

```
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($numrows > 0) {

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];
                $link = $row['link'];

                echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>$description<br /> <br />";
            }
        }
```

Comment: ok one more question now it says Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Tr\Howto\Search\search.php on line 21

Comment: $Keywords = $_GET['search'];
 
 $terms = explode(" ", $Keywords);
 $query = "SELECT *From search WHERE";
 foreach ($terms as $each){
  $i++;
  if ($i==1)
   $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
  else
   $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
 }

Comment: and it says Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Tr\Howto\Search\search.php on line 21
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%members%'' at line 1

Comment: post your complete code then i can understand your problem